# New to web developing, got an error (jsfiddle)

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I am an absolute begginer to web developing and I want to simply do a chance calculator in the online tool: jsfiddle. I got the error:"Shell form does not validate" and some strange errors after. Here is my HTML code:

```
<body>
    <form method="post">The chance of succes:
        <input type="number" name="chance">
        <br>How many tries:
        <input type="number" name="tries">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate!">
        <br>
    </form>
</body>
```

And my javascript code is:

```
function calculate(chance, tries) {
    console.log(chance / tries * 100);
}
```

As I said, I am new to this so please try to explain step by step.

Comment: Give us a link to the Fiddle

Comment: sometimes JSFiddle is a pain to debug due to it's sandbox-y nature - try doing it locally to get a clear view of what's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems. One is that your form is trying to submit itself to itself. Another is that your calculate function is never called.

Your parameters for the function are never called either. Let's change the inputs to have an id instead of a name. For example:

```
<input type="number" id="chance">
```

This makes it easier to get the value from the input when clicking the button. I've made the input a button instead of a submit, just to make sure that your form data isn't getting sent anywhere.

```
<input type="button" onclick="return calculate(getElementById('chance').value, getElementById('tries').value)" value="Calculate!">
```

Here is a jsfiddle with a possible solution for you. http://jsfiddle.net/0dmkxcab/

Comment: thank you, I understood the onclick attribute, but the "return false;" at the end of the js function is still unclear to me, can you explain that too? Also, how can I console.log the result? or may I put it into a variable? @John Stringer

Comment: That was just a precaution in case you needed the button to be a submit button. Return false is an older way of stopping the browser from performing the default action(in this case, submitting the form). You are already logging to the console, so you should be seeing the result if you open a browser inspector and check the console. You can certainly store the result of calculate into the variable, which would allow you to do cool things with it, such as display it on the screen for the user.